# Python: Select Radiobutton in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

With developing a webcrawler with Python and Selenium i want to select a radio button.
By default the "OR" option is selected and should be changed to "AND".
Unfortunately, there is no unique ID or class.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <label style="font-size:0.7vw;" for="title_description" class="col-2 col-form label"> Denominazione/Descrizione </label>
<input style="font-size:0.7vw;" type="radio" id="title_description_opt" name="title_description_opt" value="AND">and&nbsp;
<input style="font-size:0.7vw;" type="radio" id="title_description_opt" name="title_description_opt" value="OR" checked="">or&nbsp;
<input style="font-size:0.7vw;" type="radio" id="title_description_opt" name="title_description_opt" value="MP">frase esatta
<input style="font-size:0.7vw;" type="radio" id="title_description_opt" name="title_description_opt" value="CO">contiene
</div>
```

I have already tried various options, which unfortunately do not bring a solution.

e.g. `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@type='radio' and @value='AND']").click()`
But the solution leads to the following error:
`ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="title_opt" name="title_opt" type="radio"> could not be scrolled into view`

The field with the radio buttons first appears in one of the previous steps and is not visible before. Could this cause the problem. The element is visible in the Selenium browser window.

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First try by using `waits` and `element_to_be_clickable`. See if it manages to click the radio button.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="radio" and @value="AND"]'))).click()
```

If that doesn't work, Try using JS as below:

```
radio_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="radio" and @value="AND"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radio_button)
```

Imports you will need:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements_by_name("title_description_opt")[0].click()
```

numbers start from 0 in programming

> if you want to press the first button 0

> if you want to press the 2nd button 1

> if you want to press the 3rd button 2

> if you want to press the 4th button 3

[0] change this

and add this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```